# What is the best practice of pass states between tests in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to pass/share data between each test. What is the best way to implement it in Cypress?

For example:

```
 it('test 1'), () => {
   cy.wrap('one').as('a')
   const state1 = 'stat1'
 })

 it('test 2'), () => {
   cy.wrap('two').as('b')
 })

 it('test 2'), () => {
   //I want to access this.a and this.b

   //Also I want to access state1

 })
```

Comment: Tests shouldn't share state - what's the context, why do you think you need this?

Comment: Avoid using shorthand arrow functions if you want to use this.a within. Use function() { instead.

@jonrsharpe sometimes you do need it: for example 1st test retrieves something from clipboard when something is clicked, 2nd one uses this specific value to test if certain request works.

Comment: @trainoasis then your tests depend on one another and the order in which they're run, which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed, but how do you write a test like this without mocking everything or having 1 huge test? (running it as an integration/acceptance tests in CI after deployment)

Comment: @trainoasis it's hard to say without more context, but from what you've described above: just make it one test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was afraid you ll say that. Okay, will rethink a bit, tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case of Javascript variables, you can do something like this:

```js
let state;

describe('test 1', () => {
    it('changes state', () => {
        state = "hi";
     });
});

describe('test 2', () => {
    it('reports state', () => {
        cy.log(state); // logs "hi" to the Cypress log panel
     });
});
```

`.as()` does not appear to be able to carry state between `describe` blocks.

Comment: A better method is by using the current suite context: set `this.state` and you can skip having to "let" (declare) the variable in the global scope. Note that you must then use `function(){}` in place of `()=>{}` so that `this` gets assigned.

Comment: This doesn't work if *it* tests navigate to different domains.

Comment: I had to do this when I needed data from a before() to be used in later tests.

Answer (score 13):

I can see the answer worked for author, but in case anyone needs to share data between different test files, the solution is to use [cy task method](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Syntax) and store data in Node environment, e.g. in my case I needed to store user data:

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.ts
export default (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    setUserData: (userData: UserDataType) => {
      global.userData = userData;
      return null;
    },
    getUserData: () => {
      return global.userData;
    },
  });
};
```

then in test case we can do:

```js
// cypress/integration/login.spec.ts
describe('Login', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    cy.visit('/login-page');
    cy.intercept('api/login-endpoint').as('postLogin');
    // login interactions
    cy.wait('@postLogin').then((interception) => {
      // intercept user data and store it in global variable
      cy.task('setUserData', JSON.parse(interception.response.body));
    });
    // ... further assertions
  });
});
```

later we can retrieve this data easily:

```js
// cypress/integration/otherTest.spec.ts
describe('Other test', () => {
  it('uses user data', () => {
    cy.task('getUserData').then((userData: UserDataType) => {
      console.log(userData);
      // voila! Stored data between two .spec files
    });
  });
});
```

You'll also need to extend Node TS types for this, but this answer is long enough already.

Yes, I know it is not a great way of writing tests at all, as it makes them depend on each other, but sometimes a long interaction flow in application makes it necessary.

Answer (score 10):

As `abbr` pointed out in the comments, sharing a value using a global variable will not work if the tests start on a different url.

So these do not work:

- global variable assign and read (does not matter if it is outside the `describe` / `context` block or not)
- relying on `Mocha` `this.state` (this gets cleared after the test)
- using `Cypress` [`as`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as)

What remains of course is file. [Read](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile) and [write](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#Syntax).

```js
describe("Test", () => {

  it("Can access 3000", function () {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");

    cy.writeFile("shared.json", {count: 2})
  });


  it("Can access 8000", function () {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8000");

    cy.readFile("shared.json").then(cy.log)
  });

});
```

Comment: Please note that `writeFile()` does not work with ts spec files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to pass text

```
it('test 1'), () => {
  cy.wrap('one').as('a')
}

it('test 2'), () => {
  cy.wrap({ valueName: 'two' }).as('b')
}

it('test 2'), () => {
  //I want to access this.a and this.b
  cy.get('@a').then((thisIsA) => {
    cy.log(thisIsA);
    // logs 'one'
  }

  cy.get('@b').its('valueName').then((thisIsB) => {
    cy.log(thisIsB);
    // logs 'two'
  }

  cy.get('@b').its('valueName').should('eq', 'two')
}
```

Comment: Not working in cypress 3.6.1 https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1392

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of these other solutions and they aren't working for me. Maybe things changed with recent versions. The following example should work. Note the use of function() for both tests which keeps things in context of 'this.'.

```
  it('get the value', function () {
    cy.get('#MyElement').invoke('text').as('mytext1')
  })

  it('use the value', function () {
    cy.log(this.mytext1);
  })
```

Comment: This is undefined for me

Answer (score 1):

While working on this problem, I accidentally found solution. Not sure why this works. Import any json file (this solution will not change json file)

someTest.spec.js:

```
import jsonFile from "../../fixtures/file.json"
describe('Test some feature', () =>{
      it('test feature 1', () => {
        jsonFile.anyWalueYouWant="this is value from feature 1"                          
      })

      it("test feature 2", ()=>{
        cy.log(jsonFile.anyWalueYouWant)
    })

})
```

PS: anyWalueYouWant dont need to be in this parameters.json file

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the use of session cookies

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence

Although I don't really like this, a further option, similar to the tasks is to use custom commands

```
let state = {};
Cypress.Commands.add("setState", (name, value) => {
  state[name] = value;
  return value;
});

Cypress.Commands.add("getState", () => {
  return state;
});
```

Usage is then nice and pretty ;)

```
cy.setState("item", "value");
cy.getState().then((state) => {
  cy.log(state.item); // "value"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data to JSON, then access it later with `cy.fixture()`, or `cy.readFile()`.

See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#Write-response-data-to-a-fixture-file

Answer (score -2):

You can share state between steps like this

```
describe('A suite of steps', () => {

    it('visit a page and save the url', function () {
        cy.visit('/hello-world')
        // Store url
        cy.url().as('pageUrl');
    });

    it('load page url', function () {
        // Load the page from the previous step
        cy.visit(this.pageUrl)
    });
})
```