# cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argumentLearn more

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cypress

[image]I have a problem as below. I need to test login functionality, but facing with this problem.
I looked for some solutions here in Stackoverflow as well but did not help any of them.  please look at it and kindly share your thoughts. Thank you!

```
describe("LoginFunctionality", function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();

    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
      preserve: /[\s\S]*/,
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  let href;

  let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

  Cypress.Commands.add("saveLocalStorage", () => {
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
      LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
    });
  });

  Cypress.Commands.add("restoreLocalStorage", () => {
    Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach((key) => {
      localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
    });
  });

  Cypress.Commands.add("visitMultipleURL", (url) => {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      return win.open(url, "_self");
    });
  });

  it.only("LoginFunctionality", function () {
    cy.visit("xxx");
    cy.get(".chakra-stack > .css-1n94901").click();

    cy.contains("Login with aaaa").click();

    cy.url().then((url) => {
      href = url;

      cy.log("href ", href);
    });
  });

  it.only("Verification of login", function () {
    cy.visit(href);

    cy.url().should("include", "bbbb"); //assertion of that we are in this url
  });
```

Comment: the test is failing at `cy.visit("xxx");`. Where is the url mentioned in your tests?

Comment: cy.visit("link ") hard coded

Comment: In your error message it shows that you are using a variable `href` under `cy.visit()`. Please remove the variable and hardcode the link.

Comment: I don't recommend sharing state between tests like this. Even if you make it work with some of the ideas mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050657/what-is-the-best-practice-of-pass-states-between-tests-in-cypress Try to think of a better approach to your tests.

Comment: @Alapan Das due to this login is Multiple Url visit login type. I put href for new URL. it will store it as href and use it in next login.

Comment: @totymedli  here is the question I asked. maybe you know the solution

Comment: @Luna What is the reason for the separate tests in the first place? Just move the assertion in the second test to the first one.